Nav2 removing goals from closed areas
I am working with Navigation2 on ROS2 Humble. I am working on a module for following the path inside rooms/halls. I have a path computed with NavFn planner and Compute Path Though Poses BT node which does not return a information about failure goals. 
The problem is that some points are placed inside obstacles and I am not able to remove them.
Currently I am using RemoveInCollisionGoals (with footprint) to firstly clear points on walls and then if there is a failure like on a below screen - I remove the next goal until the path is possible to compute. It works in simple cases, but won't work when goals are places in slalom pattern. Is there any solution for that inside Nav2? I couldn't find any parameter that allows me to cover with "LETHAL" that areas inside obstacles, did I miss something?
I would be thanksful for advices about that!

